# Facebook login for android app using Firebase throws Exception: Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to enable facebook login in my android app using firebaseUI. I have configured my app in facebook developer page and also in firebase.
Below is the code for handling facebook access token -

```
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                            mStatusTextView.setText("Logged in as: "+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());

                            // send to game menu
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, GameMenu.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Logged in as : "+ mAuth.getCurrentUser());

                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
```

But when I try to login using facebook I get below error -

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook:{"error":{"message":"(#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"FKCMN4gqtan"}} ]
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcf.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzbb.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcz.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdc.onFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcj.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
2018-10-08 16:50:50.130 10978-10978/company.com.myapp D/FacebookLogin: Logged in as : null
```

I am using these tutorials - 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin?authuser=0

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

I have verified the app ID and app secret and I have also added the facebook account which I am using to log in as a tester for the app.

Any leads will be appreciated.